# C# Write 8 bits packet divided in 3 ints

Tags: c#, integer, bit, packet, bitarray

I need to write a 8 bit packet, that includes 3 ints, in this division:

```
int1 = 1 bit
int2 = 1 bit
int3 = 6 bit
```

I don't know how to do that. I can write some 4 bytes packets, using this function which work for us:

```
buffer.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(_value));
```

But I need help in writing a 8 bit packet divided in many ints (or bit elements). I have read about BitArray, but I really don't know how to use it. I have written some code, but don't know if it really is going to work:

```
bool playback = false;
bool extExerciseNum = false;
BitArray byte4 = new BitArray(2);
byte4.Set(0, playback);
byte4.Set(1, extExerciseNum);
```

Here I pretend to create a BitArray with the first 2 individual ints.

```
int exerciseNumber = 23;
BitArray b = new BitArray(new int[] { exerciseNumber });
int[] bits = b.Cast<bool>().Select(bit => bit ? 1 : 0).ToArray();
```

And here, I pretend to write a 6 bit length BitArray (I don't understand it properly, by the way).

Anyone can help me how to write this package properly? Thank you so much!!

Comment: Just shift them in. Which order do they need to be in?

Comment: That order: 1 bit first; then another 1 bit; and finally, at the end, the 6 bits int.

Comment: Within a byte, "first" does not make sense. The question from @TheGeneral was if int1 should occupy the most signitficant bit (MSB) or the least significant bit (LSB)

Comment: Yes sorry, int1 occupy the MSB

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `int1` should occupy the most signitficant bit (MSB), use bit shift and or to produce the 8 bit value:

```
byte result = (byte)((int1 << 7) | (int2 << 6) | int3);
```

(no range check included).
For the other bit order (`int1` should occupy the least signitficant bit):

```
byte result = (byte)(int1 | (int2 << 1) | (int3 << 2));
```

Comment: Thank you so much! So maybe, the final code will look like this (using the ints: 1, 0 and 23)?:                                      
        byte result = (byte)((1 << 7) | (0<< 6) | 23);